# Looking for a copy of Algebraic Number Theory in honor of Iwasawa

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for an electronic copy of this volume:

Advanced studies in Pure Mathematics, Volume 17
Algebraic Number Theory - in honor of K. Iwasawa
Edited by J. Coates, R. Greenberg, B. Mazur and I. Satake
August, 1989

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Thank you!

Comment: My university's library has a copy... if you are affiliated with a university you could probably get a copy through interlibrary loan.

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard, note the request for an *electronic* copy. Interlibrary loan would likely be a physical copy unless the request is for a particular article.  The OP should clarify if the copy really must be electronic or if something quaint like a bound set of pages is acceptable.

Comment: In fact, I am looking for a copy of a particular article (the one written by Monsky - if anyone has this particular article, it would be great to have it as a standalone). But I thought it would be nice to have an electronic copy of the whole volume because there are a few interesting articles there that would be nice to have access to easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download PDF files at project euclid https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aspm/
for volumes 1 to 25.